# For some reason my object rearranges when passed down as props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm getting data as an 'array of arrays', so I have to change it to an 'array of objects' so I can use it on my products page.

In the main products page, I am transforming it correctly, and using console.log, I can correctly see the 'array of objects'. After I pass down this 'array of objects' to my product page so I can use the data in the 'array of objects', the individual objects are rearranged and messed up. I've been trying to understand what went wrong but I cannot debug this. Please help.

My products page:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";

function Products() {
  //State management for the data pulled using fetch
  // data comes in as an array of arrays
  // so I have to transform into an array of objects
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // using the first array in the 'array of arrays' as keys
  const keys = data.shift();

  // transforming from 'array of arrays' to 'array of objects'
  const dataObj = data.map(elem => ({ 
    [keys[0]]: elem[0], 
    [keys[1]]: elem[1], 
    [keys[2]]: elem[2], 
    [keys[3]]: elem[3], 
  }));

  console.log(dataObj)

  // pulling data from excel sheet
  const getData = () => {
    fetch(
      "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1DpaMUmqYxGUKnT9BL0uBuCZ6WJ8vd1CLAklqUvkcA8M/values/Sheet1?alt=json&key=AIzaSyD6o4v215zWtw-kOqGVeuLG50pE2QeRZTg",
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // console.log(data.value);
        setData(data.values);
        
      });
  };

  
  return (
    <div>
      Hello, you're in the products page
      <button onClick={getData}>click me</button>
      {dataObj.map((prod) => (
        <Product prod={prod} key={prod.id}/>
        
      ))}
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

My products page

```
import React from "react";


function Product(props) {
  
  console.log(props.prod);

  
    return (

      <div>
        
      </div>
    
    );
}

export default Product;
```

[picture of my console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXTlf.png)

Ignore the empty array pls. The first array is my 'array of objects' and it is arranged properly, but the other parts are the individual objects and they are messed up.

Edit: [data.value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CYh.png)

Comment: Could you share what's in the data.values?

Comment: I really recommend narrowing down the issue. You should know the exact line that transforms the data in a way that is unexpected, and then you can ask a simpler question with less extraneous code. But honestly, you'll likely have it figured out along the way to narrowing the problem.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov I've added an edit with what data.values looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) is a mutation. Never ever ever ever ever ever mutate things in react.

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever ever mutate things *held in state* in React. Other mutations can be fine, like with `useRef` for example.

Comment: You're a life saver. Used slice instead of shift cause slice doesn't directly mutate the array. Got my data correctly! Thanks, @henryWoody

Comment: @HenryWoody - don't mutate props either. You're correct of course that mutations on `useRef` are fine BUT, in general, mutations just plain suck. Just treat all data as immutable and you'll never have to go on these types of bughunts. You'll know when it's absolutely required to perform a mutation as opposed to creating a new object, because the perf hit will be obvious and those times are usually restricted to "renders that happen on keystroke"